# Hook button press event in another application

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

I’ve to develop an application that has to track the button press event of a button which in another application. After some research I found that Windows Hooks might work for me and I’d develop a sample application that hooks the button press event in another application.

The problem I’m facing with that sample application, gets the control after the button is pressed whereas I need to get the control before the button is pressed i.e., First the sample application should get the control so, that it can grab the information from that dialog and, then after the control goes to the actual event handler of that button in other application.

I’ve already tried WH_CALLWNDPROC, WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, WH_GETMESSAGE, & WH_SYSMSGFILTER. Using WH_CALLWNDPROC hook I’m able to hook the button press but my application gets the control after the button press event handler is executed but my requirement is to get the control before the button press event handler is executed.

I’ve used the Wilson GlobalHooks to hook the application in C#. Here is the [link](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/18638/using-window-messages-to-implement-global-system-h) to it.

Comment: What message are you trying to get?

Comment: we are trying to track WM_COMMAND

Comment: Which function do you use to send the *WM_COMMAND* message to your app?

Comment: We are automating a third party application for which we don't have the source code. So, we don't know which function it uses to send WM_COMMAND message. Probably it would be SendMessage.

Comment: I dont get it! You say you do not have access to the code in the *dll* which actually inserts the `hook` but in your question: "*I’ve already tried WH_CALLWNDPROC, WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, WH_GETMESSAGE, & WH_SYSMSGFILTER. Using WH_CALLWNDPROC hook....*"!!! Which one is true???? Anyway. The most probable reason is it uses *postmessage* which returns immediately. Thus, the hooking app process the message before you get it. I can't think anything else.